# Django - Static file error using django-audiofield's template display

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I've been trying to set up functionality in my app to upload audio files, and have them be played through the front end. However, when attempting to load the audio file on the front end using the standard Django syntax `{{ work.audio_file_player|safe }}`, I receive the 404 errors for all static files the plugin includes.

```
GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/audiofield/page-player/css/page-player.css [HTTP/1.0 404 NOT FOUND 7ms]
GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/audiofield/flashblock/flashblock.css [HTTP/1.0 404 NOT FOUND 17ms]
GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/audiofield/script/soundmanager2.js [HTTP/1.0 404 NOT FOUND 22ms]
GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/audiofield/page-player/script/page-player.js [HTTP/1.0 404 NOT FOUND 21ms]
GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/audiofield/page-player/script/page-player.js [HTTP/1.0 404 NOT FOUND 5ms]
```

As far as I can tell, these errors are being thrown by the inclusion of the necessary template file from the plugin:

```
{% load staticfiles %}
{% include "common_audiofield.html" %}
```

My static file setup in `settings.py` looks like this:

```
STATIC_ROOT = ''
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(ROOT_PATH, "static/"),
)
```

I ran `sudo python manage.py collectstatic` as needed, and the static files for the parts of the site I built (css, images, etc) seem to load without an issue. Any ideas what could be causing this, or how I could work around this?

Answer (score 1):

Define STATIC_ROOT in settings.py and try:

```
python manage.py collectstatic
```